# Getting the ID from a dynamic dropdown in Laravel to use in CRUD controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working with a CRUD controller, trying to create a person.
A person belongs to a country, I have this relationship set up correctly.

In my create view, I have text boxes for user input, and a dynamic dropdown menu created from querying the Country table.

My error is when I go to create a person, I get an error - General error: 1364 Field 'country_id' doesn't have a default value.

I know this is because I'm not inserting anything into country_id because I simply don't know how to get the ID from the Country dynamic dropdown.

In my create.blade.php I have :

```
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('POST')}}
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="role" placeholder="Role"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="batting" placeholder="Batting"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="bowling" placeholder="Bowling"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="odiRuns" placeholder="Odi Runs"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image name"> <br>
    <label>Select a country:</label>
                <select name="country" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                    <option value="">--- Select Country ---</option>
                    @foreach ($countries as $country => $value)
                        <option value="{{ $country }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Create a player</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

In my controller I have -

```
        $players = new Player();

        $players->name = request('name');
        $players->age = request('age');
        $players->role = request('role');
        $players->batting = request('batting');
        $players->bowling = request('bowling');
        $players->odiRuns = request('odiRuns');
        $players->image = request('image');
        $players->country_id = request('???');

        $players->save();
```

Does anyone know how I can get the country_id value from my dynamic dropdown? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `$players->country_id = request('country');` as the select option name is country

Comment: This does allow the query to complete, but it isn't inserting the dynamic id into the field, it's just giving it a default value. For example, if I select the country with an ID of 4, it's giving the person a country ID of 1

Comment: have you var_dumped the value of `request('country')`

Comment: It's returning the actual ID-1. So where the actual ID would be 3, it returns 2.